# Help trying to identify a set and determine whether it is a subspace of $\Bbb{R}^n (n>2)$

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm trying to figure out what this set is $\{x \mid \sum_{j=1}^{n}x_j =0\}$. Also any hints on how to show this is a subspace of $\Bbb{R}^n (n>2)$?

Comment: Recall the definition of a subspace, and verify the axioms. You only have to prove $S$ is non empty, stable under sum and scalar multiplication.

Answer (score 0):

Hint for subspace: let x and x' be in that set. You know that each of them have components that add up to zero, so if you add their components together, you must also get zero. You just need to rearrange the order to get it in the form of components of the element (x + x'). Scalar multiplication is a similar idea.

Comment: So this set is the set of all column vectors that equal zero?

Comment: A column vector equals zero only if each of its components is zero, but you have (in the case n=2) [1,-1] in your set.